# Reg Ex parsing error - too many )'s

Tags: .net, regex

Using regular expressions in .NET with the pattern `^%[^%]+%\Z` and the string `"few)few%"` I get the error - `System.ArgumentException: parsing "few)few%" - Too many )'s`.

```
Dim match As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match("^%[^%]+%\Z", "few)few%")
```

What would the issue be? Do I need to escape brackets in any input expression to reg ex?

(I'm trying the determine if string has the wildcard % at the beginning and end of the string but not elsewhere in the string)

Comment: I may be in error, but it looks like you maybe should escape the backslash in your string with another backslash?

Comment: @slartibartfast: Apparently, that's not necessary in Visual Basic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, your input does not have to be escaped. You simply have your arguments the wrong way around.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z2heewz(v=VS.100).aspx):

```
public static Match Match(
    string input,
    string pattern
)
```

Comment: I had been doing it the right way around all day long too, there's something about friday evenings that makes you unable to see simple coding mistakes. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: lol I was almost pulling my hair our until I saw this answer. Stupid me. Probably because it's 1 am at night.